# How to remove the error of index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

Hello i keep getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in the line if(numList.get(x) == " " && numList.get(x+1) == " "). How do i fix this?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        String row;
        String[] data = null;
        List<String> numList = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input file lab5.csv"));
        while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
            data = row.split(",");
            // do something with the data

            for(int x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
                numList.add(data[x]);
            }
            numList.add(" ");
        }

        System.out.println("Make sure excel file is on src.\nNumbers extracted from file: "+numList);
        int n=0;

        for(int x=0; x<numList.size(); x++) {
            if(numList.get(x) == " " && numList.get(x+1) == " ") {
                n = x+1;
                break;
```

Comment: `for(int x=0; x<numList.size()-1; x++) {`?

Comment: `numList.get(x+1)` - also this is not how you compare Strings in java

Comment: Yes: don't use `==` to compare strings

Answer (score 0):

Add a check in if clause for last index handling (x < numList.size()-1)

```
if (numList.get(x) == " " && x < numList.size()-1 && numList.get(x+1) == " ") {
```

Comment: Unless it's `if (numList.get(x) == " " && (x < numList.size()-1 || numList.get(x+1) == " ")) {`